# Link within a text in another column php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a link within a text, I have 2 columns in my table (updates1) and (link1) updates 1 contains a text while link 1 contains a link. The problem is whenever im trying to call it the data or the link itself is being an output besides the text. I need it to be stored inside the text.

```
 echo "<b><h4>{$list["updates1"]}<a>{$list["link1"]}</a></b></h4><hr>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<b><h4><a href="'.$list["link1"].'">'.$list["updates1"].'</a></h4></b><hr>';
```

As per OP's example in the comment:

```
echo '<b><h4><a href="upload/'.$list["link1"].'" target=_"blank">'.$list["updates1"].'</a></b></h4><hr>';
```

Comment: I just noticed that you closed `<b>` before closing `<h4>`, as per @Thomas' answer

Comment: same thing , i need the text (updates1) to be a link containing (link1)

Comment: Check my edit, something like that? I put the `link1` in the `href` and `updates1` inside `<a>`

Comment: i tried modfying it, by any chance i dont know why my code is wrong when im trying to target it to another page

  echo "<b><h4><a href='upload/".$list["link1"]."' target_"blank">".$list['updates1']."</a></b></h4><hr>";

Comment: You forgot `=` in `target`: `"target=_blank"`

Answer (score 1):

Close the `<h4>` tag before the `<b>` tag, like this:

```
echo "<b><h4>{$list["updates1"]}<a>{$list["link1"]}</a></h4></b><hr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<b><h4>{$list['updates1']}<a href=\"{$list['link1']}\"> Your Link Title</a></h4></b><hr>";
```

EDIT: Try to close proper way tag

Answer (score 1):

**in php you can go through**

```
echo "<b><h4><a href='".$list["link1"]."'>".$list['updates1']."</a></b></h4><hr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try it using "\"

```
echo "<b><h4><a href=\"{$list['link1']}\"> {$list['updates1']}</a></h4></b><hr>";
```